# Can the ServiceWorker respond with network only if the resources are not new?

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

I have an application that works on a subdomain.
When I visit the app on that subdomain, I want the ServiceWork to serve the most up to date content.
But I want to cache and serve from the cache if the response is identical (something like the hash of the file to check that there was no update).

Is it possible to serve the network first, then cache the content and the next time serve cache first if the response wasn't updated?

At the moment I can serve from cache and fallback to network or serve only network first.
I want to serve network first if the content from the cache doesn't match the response. Is that possible?

Comment: What is the content? The reason I ask, is if it's not the root site, you should be able to just use [cache busting](https://www.keycdn.com/support/what-is-cache-busting) instead of trying to manage the content caching  yourself.

Comment: Yes, they are the static contents from the root site. 
Thank you, I will have a look at it too.